# JDBC Spring Mockito

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, mockito

I want to test this method (getDetails) is part of my DaoImpl, but I do not know how to do it. I know that I have to test the database mocking it with the JDBC template:

```
 public List<DataLoadDetail> getDetails(int fileId, String templateType, String status, int start, int end) {

    List<DataLoadDetail> list = new ArrayList<DataLoadDetail>();
    StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();

    sql.append("SELECT * FROM ( ")
        .append("SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TB_DETAIL.UPLOADITEM_SEQ_NR ASC) AS RowNum, ")
        .append("TB_DETAIL.UPLOAD_ID, TB_DETAIL.UPLOADITEM_SEQ_NR, TB_DETAIL.UPLOADITEM_ACTION_CD, ")
        .append("TB_DETAIL.UPLOADITEM_INSERT_DT, TB_DETAIL.UPLOADITEM_UPDATE_DT, TB_DETAIL.UPLOADITEM_STATUS_CD, ")
        .append("TB_DETAIL.UPLOADITEM_PAYLOAD, TB_DETAIL.UPLOADITEM_RESPONSE, TB_MESSAGE.DESCRIPTION ")
        .append("FROM DL_DETAIL TB_DETAIL LEFT JOIN DL_MESSAGE TB_MESSAGE ")
        .append("ON TB_DETAIL.UPLOAD_ID = TB_MESSAGE.UPLOAD_ID ")
        .append("AND TB_DETAIL.UPLOADITEM_SEQ_NR = TB_MESSAGE.UPLOADITEM_SEQ_NR ")
        .append("WHERE TB_DETAIL.UPLOAD_ID =:fileId ");

    if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(status, "s")) {
        sql.append(" AND TB_DETAIL.UPLOADITEM_STATUS_CD = 'S' ");
    } else if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(status, "f")) {
        sql.append(" AND TB_DETAIL.UPLOADITEM_STATUS_CD != 'S' ");
    }

    sql.append(" ) AS DT WHERE RowNum > :start ");

    if (end > 0) {
        sql.append(" AND RowNum <= :end ");
    }

    System.out.println("getDetails - File Id "+fileId+", Query --> " + sql.toString());

    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    props.put("fileId", fileId);
    props.put("start", start);
    props.put("end", end);

    list = npTemplate.query(sql.toString(), props, new DataLoadDetailRowMapper());
    return list;
}
```

The applicationContext.xml file is:

```
<bean id="dataLoadDetailDao" class="com.hp.it.mdm.dao.impl.DataLoadDetailDaoImpl">
    <property name="npTemplate">
        <ref bean="nameParamJdbcTemplate"/>
    </property>
    <property name="dlmdao">
        <ref bean="dlmdao"/>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

I have seen several posts in StackOverflow but I can not get the concept of the test.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is `verify` that the method `npTemplate.query()` was called with the specified parameters.

Your test may look like this:

```
private NameParamJdbcTemplate nTemplate = mock(NameParamJdbcTemplate.class);

@Test
public void test() {
  //given
  private DaoImpl daoImpl = new DaoImpl(nTemplate);
  //when
  daoImpl.getDetails(...);
  //then
  verify(nTemplate).query(any(), any(), any()); //or you can specify the exact parameters that should be passed.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to test there might be different types of tests.

**First** you need to test the logic of the method.
Each branch of your code must be tested (you have several if conditions).
To achieve that you have to mock `npTemplate.query()` method passing different combinations of sql query string and parameters.
All your tests will look somehow like this

```
// given
String expectedSql =
Map<String, Object> expectedProps = ...
DataLoadDetailRowMapper expectedMapper = new DataLoadDetailRowMapper();
List<DataLoadDetail> expectedResult = ...
NpTemplate npTemplate = Mockito.mock(NpTemplate.class);
BDDMockito.given(npTemplate.query(expectedSql, props, expectedMapper))
        .willReturn(expectedResult);
DaoImpl dao = ... // Initialize it using the mocked npTemplate.

// when
List<DataLoadDetail> result = dao.getDetails(); // pass needed parameters

// then
assertThat(result, is(expectedResult));
```

I didn't use static imports just to make clear which classes were used. But it is preferable to import everything statically in unit tests.

**Second** thing is the query itself, you have to test the sql code. To achieve that you might make data setup use inmemory db (for instance H2) and run the sql over it.